# Cannot config all hikari instances in multitenancy

Tags: spring, spring-boot, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I'm using Hikari 2.6.1 with Spring boot 1.4.2 for a multitenant app, with every tenant (with every new database connection) new instance of hikari gets created, the first instance which is created at startup is configured correctly with the conf provided in `application.properties`, but the next instances gets the default conf of hikari.

this is my hikari config in `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.connection-timeout=300000
spring.datasource.max-lifetime=500000
spring.datasource.idle-timeout=400000
spring.datasource.maximum-pool-size=20
spring.datasource.minimumIdle=20
```

How could i configure all hikari instances with the config above.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to create a Configuration class for DatabaseConfiguration. You may need to configure Hikari as follows 
                    `HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
                config.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
                config.setDataSourceClassName(dataSourceClassName);
                config.addDataSourceProperty("url", DbUrl);
                config.addDataSourceProperty("user", user);
                config.addDataSourceProperty("password", password);
                HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(config);`